# Access is Denied to Airflow webserver

Tags: google-cloud-composer

When accessing Airflow through the Google Composer Environments page in the GCP Console I get an error,

```
Access is Denied
```

In IAM I have the 'Owner' role so should have permission to access this. My understanding is that Composer uses IAM for access control,

https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/access-control

However even with the full access given to me by the Owner role I am still unable to access the UI.

Do you know how access to Google Composer is working and how I can resolve this issue?

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcPOX.png)

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot? Is your access denied by Airflow or by Cloud IAP?

Comment: @hexacyanide Added a screenshot to the question with screenshot, being denied by Airflow

Comment: That's strange. Cloud Composer does use IAM, but it looks like IAP let you through, then Airflow locked you out. Did anyone in your environment enable RBAC, or use `create_user`?

Comment: I just have all of the default settings except 
`dags_are_paused_at_creation
True`

Comment: Think I will just recreate the environment and start again :/

Comment: Does creating a new environment work for you?